# simplecv ubuntu 14.04 install

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, raspberry-pi2, simplecv

I'm trying to install SimpleCV on a RaspberryPi 2 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I don't believe this to be be specific to the Pi or even to Ubuntu, it is more a general question and I feel OK to ask here.

I'm following the directions at
 https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/develop/doc/HOWTO-Install%20on%20RaspberryPi.rst

When trying the first part of step 4 I get a long list of trace then a "memory error"

When trying the second part I get the following error

```
Collecting PIL (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
No matching distribution found for PIL (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
```

and breaking it further down I get an error trying to install PIL by itself (well, forcing it really, but apparently not hard enough...)

```
robert@furbot:~/Code/SimpleCV$ pip install --allow-external  --allow-unverified    PIL
Collecting PIL
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

I notice that PIL is itself deprecated and wonder if there's a better way to do this ? The SSL error is common on this system it's a cause for concern but it's not really a mission critical exercise either. The goal is as said to install SimpleCV on a Ubuntu 14.04 system. I already have openCV compiled locally and it seems OK and I believe the system itself should be OK (I have a backup of its SD card...)

TIA
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues with installing PIL a few days ago on a Macbook. I ended up skipping that step altogether and proceeding with the other installs. When I tried to run the helloworld program, it threw a couple errors along the lines of "`could not find x in PIL library`," so I installed the `pillow` library instead, which was recommended in countless other SO questions related to PIL. It seemed to work fine after that. I know it's a different system from an RPi2, but I'd say give it a shot.

It would probably be easier here to follow the "install SimpleCV from source" instructions under step 4. Since it's looking for `PIL` in your `requirements.txt`, go ahead and edit that file to remove `PIL` from the list before running the line: `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`. If that doesn't work, try replacing `PIL` with `pillow`.